# -moz-use-text-color not work in chrome And IE9+

Tags: html, css

I add `-moz-use-text-color` for `border-color` Like This :

```
.booksline{

border-image: none;
margin: 0 auto 0px;
width: 96%;
height:220px;
padding:20px 20px 20px 0;
border-width: 1px 1px medium;
border-style: solid solid none;
border-color: #EAE9E9 #EAE9E9 -moz-use-text-color;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
border-image: none;
background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

In Action  I add `#EAE9E9` border color But this not work in Chrome And IE 9+ and show black border color. this good/true work with FF. how do fix this?!

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/4ptokwrh/

Answer (score 1):

Look this updated DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/4ptokwrh/3/

You will need to use -webkit-* prefix for chrome specific CSS

Example for Chrome
`-webkit-border-start-color: transparent;`

Example for IE
`border-left-color: transparent;`

Actually most properties with no prefix are cross-browser compatible, so prefer to write them that way, whenever possible

Remember to look what properties are supported by what browsers

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-*` prefixed css will work only in firefox, and `-moz-use-text-color` is deprecated, use `currentColor` instead.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/currentColor